# Getting jdk.unsupported while running EAR on JBoss which was build using Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jboss

We are trying to run EAR appplication which was built using gradle on Jboss server and getting the ffollowing errro.
JDK version is 8.
Wildfly version is 8.

```
18:58:04,899 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.Dragon6.ear.Dragon6Web.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.Dragon6.ear.Dragon6Web.war".main: JBAS018759: Failed to load module: deployment.Dragon6.ear.Dragon6Web.war:main
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:91) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_342]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_342]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [rt.jar:1.8.0_342]
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: jdk.unsupported:main
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1050) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1406) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1434) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:242) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:70) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    ... 5 more

18:58:04,904 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "Dragon6.ear")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.Dragon6.ear.Dragon6Web.war\".main" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service.\"deployment.Dragon6.ear.Dragon6Web.war\".main: JBAS018759: Failed to load module: deployment.Dragon6.ear.Dragon6Web.war:main
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: jdk.unsupported:main"}}
```

Checked Compatability so Java version is 8 and wildfly version is also 8 which seems compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade Wildfly: Wildfly 8 is quite old and may not be fully compatible with Java 8. You could upgrade to a newer version of Wildfly that supports Java 8.

OR, you could downgrade your JVM to earlier version of Java 8.

If your application has explicit dependencies on the `jdk.unsupported` module, you should remove or update those dependencies.

Comment: This is not accurate. Wildfly 8 is compatible with Java 8: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/262103

Comment: Which version is this ? WildFly 8.2.1 doesn't have a jdk.unsupported module

Answer (score 0):

You have a manifest file in one of your jar which contains **Dependencies: jdk.unsupported** (could be spring-core). This is what is causing the error. Either create a jdk.unsupported fake module or fix your dependencies or upgrade WildFly (which you should do in any case as a 10 years old out of date software is quite hazardous)
To create the fake module:

1. mkdir- p $JBOSS_PATH/modules/system/layers/base/jdk/unsupported/main
2. Create a new file under the main folder named module.xml with the following content: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5" name="jdk.unsupported"> </module>`